# Publish to folder disappeared after update 2 - visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web, publish

As I always doing right clicking project

Clicking publish site but only below screen appears. No regular publish to folder option.

[image]

This happened after Visual Studio 2012 Update 2

How to solve this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the drop down menu and create a new profile with the settings you want.